# Regex find text before some characters

Tags: python, regex, split

I have big files like this:

```
f = """
(function ($hx_exp, $g) { 
var A = function() { };
$hxCls[1] = $hxCls["A"] = A;
A.__name__ = ["A"];
A.__get = function(d,e) {
     return "a"; 
};
var B = function(a,c) {
    this.r = new Func1(a,c);
};
$hxCls[2] = $hxCls["B"] = B;
B.__name__ = ["B"];
B.prototype = {
   r: null,
   map: function(s,f) { return 0; },
   __class__: B
};
}(this));
"""
```

I want split this text into like this:

```
var A = function() { };
$hxCls[1] = $hxCls["A"] = A;
A.__name__ = ["A"];
A.__get = function(d,e) {
        return "a"; 
};
```

I use regexp:

```
re.findall(r"(^var.+)", txt)
```

But I fund only lines:

> var A = function() { };
>
> var B = function(a,c) {

Maybe someone knows libraries that can break such large `JavaScript` files into several others.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^[ \t]+var .*(?:\r?\n(?!(?:[ \t]+var |\S)).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/hggM4q/1 Note that it is not a good idea to match programming code with a regex. Perhaps you should consider using a parser instead.

Comment: This option also produces only a string, but I was a little mistaken, I have no tabs between the contents `(function`

Comment: Try it like this `^var .*(?:\r?\n(?!(?:var)).*)*\r?\n};`  https://regex101.com/r/0XLgNc/1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
re.finditer(r"var\s\w\s=.*?(?=var\sB|\}\(this\))", txt, re.DOTALL)
```

Test: https://regex101.com/r/2O6rgN/1/

Comment: This option doesn't find anything. If i change to `re.findall(r"^var.*?(?=var\sB|\}\(this\))", i, re.DOTALL)`. But I was a little mistaken, I have no tabs between the contents `(function`